# Panel data: dealing with lagging and binary dependent variable with plm

Tags: r, panel, plm

I am attempting to run a pooled logistic regression with panel data and a binary dependent variable.  Since I wanted to lag some of the variables, I used the plm package to create them.  When I tried to do it other  ways, I ran into problems.  I can't use lag or embed, because it is panel data.

```
hybridsubsidies <-pdata.frame(reduced, c("state","year"))

lagee<-(lag(hybridsubsidies$eespending,1))
lagratio<-(lag(hybridsubsidies$ratio, 1))
laggopvote<-(lag(hybridsubsidies$gopvote, 1))
laggasoline<-(lag(hybridsubsidies$gasoline, 1))
```

I wanted to put all the variables into the original data frame (hybridsubsidies) before I ran the pooled analysis.  I'm pretty sure I don't need to, but I'm a visual person, and would like to verify the format of the data is appropriate before running any analysis.

From the output below, it looks like everything is done correctly.

> head(lag(hybridsubsidies$eespending,1))
>
> ALABAMA-1999 ALABAMA-2000 ALABAMA-2001 ALABAMA-2002 ALABAMA-2003 ALABAMA-2004
>
> ```
>      NA        58294        55378        26982        28264         2566
> ```
>
> head(hybridsubsidies$eespending)
>
> ALABAMA-1999 ALABAMA-2000 ALABAMA-2001 ALABAMA-2002 ALABAMA-2003 ALABAMA-2004
>
> ```
>   58294        55378        26982        28264         2566        26906
> ```

My problem is that when I try and assign this lag variable as a vector in the data frame, this way,

```
hybridsubsidies$lagee<-(lag(hybridsubsidies$eespending,1))
```

it does so(when I call the names in the dataframe, they are included), but then I can no longer view the dataframe.  R says to me:

> Error in edit.data.frame(get(subx, envir = parent), title = subx, ...) :
> can only handle vector and factor elements

How can I solve this so that I can view the data frame before I run the analysis?  I want to look at it, since it looks like I will have to use glm instead of plm (pooling)  for this analysis since the dependent variable is a binary variable and plm does not support these d.v.'s

This has been giving me problems for awhile now.

> col1   ST   YR   EELAG  EE
>
> [1,]    1      1       NA    58294
>
> [2,]    1    2  58294  55378
>
> [3,]    1    3  55378  26982
>
> [4,]    1    4  26982  28264
>
> [5,]    1    5  28264   2566
>
> [6,]    1    6   2566  26906
>
> [7,]    1    7  26906  29466
>
> [8,]    2    1     NA    355
>
> [9,]    2    2    355    259
>
> [10,]    2    3    259    224
>
> [11,]    2    4    224    217
>
> [12,]    2    5    217    241
>
> [13,]    2    6    241    231
>
> [14,]    2    7    231    231
>
> [15,]    3    1     NA   5111
>
> [16,]    3    2   5111   3753
>
> [17,]    3    3   3753   2211
>
> [18,]    3    4   2211   1452
>
> [19,]    3    5   1452   2913
>
> [20,]    3    6   2913   3128
>
> [21,]    3    7   3128   7132
>
> [22,]    4    1     NA   1597
>
> [23,]    4    2   1597    905

Comment: I don't think that lag is doing what you think - look at the border between different states or years.

Comment: Hadley, I checked the data frame, and it looks like it is doing what I want it to.  please see above.

Comment: I thought that if I was using the pdata.frame from the plm package, then the data frame is converted into a times series object.  Since it has the unit and time id, I think lag is doing what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lag` returns a time series object.  Does

```
hybridsubsidies$lagee<-(as.vector(lag(hybridsubsidies$eespending,1)))
```

work?

Comment: why yes it does.  i thought it had to do with the class of the objects, but couldn't figure it out.  that really helps, thanks!

Comment: when you look at the help on functions always pay attention to the return types, and coerce them if necessary.  R sometimes coerces automatically, and sometimes not.

Note:  I am not sure why `class(lag(v,1))` returns integer if v is an integer.  I would expect it to return ts.  Perhaps someone with more knowledge than I can say.

Comment: i just looked to see what type of data that that command returns (without including as.vector in the command), and it returns a 'double,' which is a vector... so i'm not sure as to why i would have to set the lagged variable as a vector.  when i checked the type of the object when i included as.vector in the command, it returned 'double' still. 

hopefully someone can explain this

Comment: if you display the data, you will see that it is not in fact a vector.  You can also see this by using is.vector()

You should also take note of Hadley's comment that lag probably isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Ok, now I understand.  A time series object is just a vector, but with the attribute of `tsp` added.  I'm not sure why it does not add an attribute of `class`, but it doesn't.

All lag does is modify the `tsp` attribute.